# Position div vertically in the middle

Tags: css

How would I go about setting up a div horizontally/vertically in the middle?

Here is my code so far:

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="signin_header">
        Sign in
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
html {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    display: table-cell;
}
#outer {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
}
#inner {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    background-image: none;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-size: auto;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-right-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-top-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'segoe ui', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 25px;
}
#signin_header {
    color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
    display: block;
    font-family: 'segoe ui', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 283px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Fiddle can be found here

http://jsfiddle.net/yaFeD/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after? I think this is what you were wanting?

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
html {
display: table;
margin: auto;
height: 100%;
}
body {
display: table-cell;
}
#outer {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
height: 100%;
position:relative;
top:50%;
bottom:50%;
}
#inner {
display: inline-block;
background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-size: auto;
border-bottom-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-left-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-right-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-top-color: rgb(229, 229, 229);
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1px;
display: block;
font-family: 'segoe ui', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
width: 300px;
padding: 25px;
}
#signin_header {
color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
display: block;
font-family: 'segoe ui', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: normal;
height: 16px;
line-height: 16px;
margin-top: 0px;
width: 283px;
text-align: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EQjHz/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to center the Sign In div (not the lettering itself) this is the new CSS you would need, tested in your jsfiddle, by using `margin: 0 auto;` and `position: relative;` your setting the div in the middle of that div.

```
#signin_header {
    color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
    display: block;
    font-family: 'segoe ui', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 283px;
}
```

edit: i also took your `text-align: left;` out

Comment: I'm trying to center the actual div

Comment: Right, that achieves centering the DIV itself, actually it puts it straight in the middle, centered horizontal and vertical. If you want your text to stay aligned to the left of the div you can still keep it, i just assumed you were wanting the text to be center along with he div being centered as well.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `margin:auto;` to the inner-div will do the trick.
When you only want horizontal alignment, add only `margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;`.
Likewise for vertical alignment, add `margin-bottom:auto;margin-top:auto;`